# How to paste a copied selection in the same spot as the original selection?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have Photoshop CC installed on many machines and the behavior in question happens randomly. Or I keep doing something seamless that I pay attention to that results in this behavior. To recap: I make a selection on a layer, I copy that selection and then I paste. This results in a new layer being created on top of the original layer, composed of that copied selection, but the position of that layer is shifted randomly. I want the newly created layer/pasted selection to appear in the same exact position (on top of the original layer).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a selection is *active*, then the paste command will paste in the center of the *selection*.

If NO selection is active, then the paste will paste in the center of the *canvas*.

If you want to copy a selection to a new layer, retaining the existing position for the copy, you may find <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> a better shortcut. It copies, creates a new layer above, and pastes all in 1 step. The menu item for this is located at `Layer > New > Layer via Copy`.

Comment: Scott, if all responses to my questions came in the format you provided, I'd find myself eating less candy bars! Thank you. =)

Comment: Glad I could help @brooklynsweb `:)`